# opening powerpoint using excel vba on a macintosh

Tags: vba, excel

I have done a lot of research on this topic, and can't seem to find anything that works for me. 
What my project does is the user fills out the excel file with data. The user presses finish which takes the excel data and auto populates it into a powerpoint. The powerpoint "called "ExcelUseThisOne") is already made and is saved in a folder (called "PowerPoint") on the desktop. I want the excel file to open the powerpoint, auto populate it, save it, then close powerpoint.
I have this working on a PC, but not a Mac.
Here is my code on opening powerpoint which I thought would work, but doesn't:

```
UserName = InputBox(Prompt:="You name please.", Title:="ENTER YOUR NAME", Default:="all LOWERCASE and ONE WORD")
Dim strPresPath As String, strExcelFilePath As String, strNewPresPath As String
strPresPath = ":Users:" & UserName & ":Desktop:PowerPoint:ExcelUsesThisOne.ppt"
FilePath = ":Users:" & UserName & ":Desktop:PowerPoint:NewPresentation.ppt"
strNewPresPath = FilePath
Set oPPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
oPPTApp.Visible = msoTrue
Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.Presentations.Open(strPresPath)
```

Any help would be great! Thank you.

Comment: *but doesn't:* **<<** What does this mean? Do you get an error? Which line?

Comment: Yes I do get an error. It says: Run-time error '-2147483640 (80000008)': Method 'Open' of object 'Presentations' failed. My guess is that it cannot find the file because I have incorrect verbiage for describing where the file is located (on the desktop in a folder called "PowerPoint")

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain but I seem to recall that Mac does **not** use file extensions, so you could try this on Mac:

```
strPresPath = ":Users:" & UserName & ":Desktop:PowerPoint:ExcelUsesThisOne"
```

Other possible reason is that the username has been entered incorrectly? I think this will work on a mac, instead of the input box you can try one of these options:

```
strPresPath = ":Users:" & Environ("username") & ":Desktop:PowerPoint:ExcelUsesThisOne"
```

Or try that approach with the file extension (again, I'm not 100% certain about the file extensions not used on Mac OS).

You may need to volume name, e.g.,:

```
strPresPath = "volume_name:Users:..."`
```

Otherwise, you can debug by checking the path of some other workbook, which should show you the correct way to formulate the path string.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help David!! I tried the first two and got the same error message. For the third one, I got an error message that said "Run-time error '429': ActiveX component can't create object"   My code is initially able to open powerpoint, but it brings up the "PowerPoint Presentation Gallery". Then I get the error message. I am not sure if that is throwing off my code or not, but its just an observation. When I open my powerpoint ExcelUseThisOne, it doesn't open that (Powerpoint presentation gallery). Let me know your thoughts. Thank you!!

Comment: meh I think it's more than I can help with. If I had a Mac, I could figure it out, but I don't, so I was mostly just taking a shot in the dark here.  If the third option doesn't work with the `ActiveX` error, then you won't be able to use that on a Mac, of that I am about 100% certain. The other two giving you an error, it is either related to the "Gallery" (I don't know what this is, can you add a screenshot?) or the file path is bad.

Comment: Can you debug by checking the path of some other workbook (e.g., `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.FullName`, which should show you the correct way to formulate the path string?

Comment: Hi David, Gallery thing is the same thing on Windows when you say select a new project. It presents all of the different kinds of workbooks (or in this case presentations) you can open up. Sorry, but I can't find how to paste a picture on this website. The path of my workbook is "DIALSSD:Users:myname:Desktop:Final_Copy.xlsm